# Can't get my .js to work in my Dreamweaver file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver

I am following a video tutorial for creating a sticky navigation after some scrolling, and I have almost completely copied the html, css, and js, but still nothing seems to be happening for me.

I have a hunch that the issue lies in file placements. But after hours of trying to fix the problem, I'm honestly at a complete loss of what to do next. I need another set of eyes.

All I am trying to do at the moment, is get an 'alert' to pop up when I refresh the page, letting me know how many pixels the nav bar is from the top.

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Stickey Navigation</title>

<link href="../Styles/sample-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/sample-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<!--container-->
<div class="container">

    <h1>Sample Header</h1>

    <!--navigation-->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--end navigation-->

    <h2>Content Header</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</div>
<!--end container-->
```

CSS

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
margin: 100px;
padding: 20px;
box-shadow: 10px #333;
}

nav {
max-width: 100%;
background: #999;
}

nav ul, li {
display: inline-block;
background: #999;
margin: 0;
padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
font-size: 4.6em;
}
```

JS/jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;
alert(navOffset);


});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to eat the pizza before you make it. You try to use jQuery before you load jQuery.

There is also no need to include the min version and the dev version of the same file. Load only one.

Your includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/sample-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

The way it should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/sample-script.js"></script>
```